Is there an estimate for how many monopoles would be produced in the very early universe?
The question really hits it with this one. I haven't really found some good numbers other than the whole “It'd be so many (per Hubble vol) to recollapse the universe”. I don't know if that comes of as me being lazy but I'd like to see some estimates?

Related: https://arxiv.org/abs/2406.08728 and references therein for a bound on the possible number. It discusses Magnetic Black Holes, but the theory in Section 2 is still very relevant.

A fairly detailed explanation can be found in Preskill's Magnetic Monopole review (Ann. Rev. Nucl. Part. Sci. 1984.34 : 461-530) here: https://www.phenix.bnl.gov/WWW/publish/wasiko/Monopole/Reviews/Preskill_84.pdf

Thank you @CompassBearer :)
